# Console.WriteLine variables, do they have to be called and answered in numeric order?

Tags: c#, .net

I don't really know much enough to easily describe it to you, but instead I'll just show you examples.
**Do we have to do this:**

```
public void Display() 
{    
Console.WriteLine("VariableOne: {0} VariableTwo: {1} VariableThree: {2}", variableone, variabletwo, variablethree);
}
```

**Or can we do this as well?**

```
public void Display()
{
Console.WriteLine("VariableOne: {2} VariableTwo: {1} VariableThree: {0}", variablethree, variabletwo, variableone);
}
```

Excuse my mistakes, I attempted to format as best as I could.

*If you didn't get what I meant, I was just showing the difference in how I called {#}, where # is the different number between the variables in the first argument, I'm just asking how flexible this is, or how rigid and case-sensitive C# really is.*

Comment: Why don't you try it first in a Visual Studio?

Comment: It seems to me that you could test this yourself in far less time than it took you to post here. Is there a reason you didn't do so? This should be the place you ask for help **after** you've tried to do things yourself and run into problems, not an excuse for doing absolutely nothing yourself.

Comment: @KenWhite Why are you discouraging me from learning? I simply asked this because I could, and because I knew I would have a decent chance about learning a lot more about it then I could be just typing it out and getting a result.

Comment: I'm *encouraging* you to learn, by not expecting to have your hand held to do anything at all. You learn far more by actually doing than you do by having others do it for you. What happens when for some reason you can't get to this site and have to figure out something on your own, if you can't even figure out the answer to a simple issue? You could have done this by simply changing the order of the variables and running the code; it's simply wrong to have to have others do it for you because you're afraid to make the effort yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are called Placeholders, It is all about indexing.

> A [composite format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd(v=vs.110).aspx) string consists of fixed text intermixed with
>   indexed placeholders, called format items, that correspond to the
>   objects in the list. The formatting operation yields a result string
>   that consists of the original fixed text intermixed with the string
>   representation of the objects in the list.

By specifying `"VariableOne: {2}"` it will takes the third value or the value @ index 2 in the list of arguments supplied. Let me assume that variables are of type integers and are defined as follows:

```
int variablethree=3, variabletwo=2, variableone=1;
```

Now consider the second case :

```
Console.WriteLine("VariableOne: {2} VariableTwo: {1} VariableThree: {0}", variablethree, variabletwo, variableone);
```

Which will gives you the output as `VariableOne: 1 VariableTwo: 2 VariableThree: 3`. Since `{2}` will takes the value at the index `2` which is `variableone`

Comment: Thanks! I get it, and now I remember an important programming & vocab word, Indexes.

Answer (score 3):

Numbered placeholders are used to permit proper localization. Different spoken languages prefer to structure sentences in different orders, having numbered placeholders gives the translator the freedom to rearrange the sentence to be more appropriately worded for a given spoken language.

User visible text is often stored outside the code, and looked up based on the current language. The term used in windows is "resources". This allows the language translators to add more languages without having to look through program source code. The translator edits the format string, and the program code can just pass the values in a fixed order.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this instead if you prefer.

```
Console.WriteLine($"VariableOne: {variableone} VariableTwo: {variabletwo} VariableThree: {variablethree}";
```

Comment: Cool, the documentation and learning PDF I'm reading didn't say anything about this.

Comment: It is a fairly new addition to c# afaik

Comment: Interesting, is C# considered to be at all outdated? Or is it just old and is still being updated like PHP?

Comment: Not at all. .NET is still very young compared to C/C++ and development is extremely active. I believing C# is still growing in popularity as well. There have been some quite dramatic updates in the years gone by, more so than I've ever seen for C++ etc